# WP7, C#, Increase slider value by holding a button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button, slider

I have to increase the slider control value while holding a button.
As long as I am holding the button the slider has to keep increasing.

For example, the scenario is typical with volume control.
I have a slider for volume and a button `Increase` for volume.
Now as long as I keep holding the `Increase` button, the volume (marker) in the slider should keep increasing continuously till I release the button.

What I have achieved is changing the value of the slider on individual **click** events on the button.
Kindly give your suggestions on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [book](http://books.google.ru/books?id=glwnDTkn64kC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=windows%20phone%207%20repeatbutton&source=bl&ots=y40dPx74ul&sig=mOR_NGOsVANENAi6O82SxI96rZ0&sa=X&ei=5L41UJKuE4bh4QTku4H4Ag&ved=0CC0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=windows%20phone%207%20repeatbutton&f=false) there should be RepeatButton. In this case it will perfectly suit your needs. Try to avoid Thread sleeps. Freezes are not pretty good thing. It's one of first candidates for refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public bool Ok = false;

    public void Do()
    {
        while (Ok)
        {
            this.Text += ".";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Application.DoEvents();
            //I added dots to the form text , You do your own mission
        }
    }

    private void btnLouder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Ok = true;
        Do();
    }

    private void btnLouder_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Ok = false;
    }
```

Add a TrackBar control to the form and then
Replace the code in While block with this one, it does exactly what you want :

```
if(trackBar1.Value < trackBar1.Maximum)
    trackBar1.Value += 1;
```

Comment: Please use the RepeatButton instead of this. A while(true) loop in a Click event, Thread.Sleep and Application.DoEvents right after each other hurts my eyes.